# How to run "Run Bar" commands?

Tags: c#, batch-file

I need to run a command "control bthprops.cpl" in a C# program. This command brings up Bluetooth Settings control panel window. I tried running it using Process.Start() but the bluetooth window doesn't show up. I also tried writing a BAT file to the disk and executing it though my program, but still has the same problem. Is there any way to accomplish this?

```
//Dump BAT File and execute it
string path = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()+"startBT.bat";
string[] content = {"control bthprops.cpl"};
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(path, content);

//Execute BAT file
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = path;
p.Start();
```

Comment: Show us the exact ucode you use with Process.Start()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to go with a BAT file, this single line ought to open the specified control panel;

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("control", "bthprops.cpl");
```

Since I don't have aforementioned bthprops.cpl; at least this works on W7 (open desktop settings)

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("control", "desk.cpl");
```

If your control panel has tabs, you can even select what tab to open;

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("control", "bthprops.cpl,,2");
```

Comment: It does work for "desk.cpl" but not for "bthpros.cpl". Any insights?

Comment: Where exactly is bthprops.cpl located?

Comment: In C:\Windows\System32

Comment: ATTENTION: This works ONLY if your application runs as 64 process on a 64 bit Windows. To make it work in a 32 bit application on a 64 bit Windows read my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Supply the full path and start it, for example:

```
var path = Path.Combine(Environment.SystemDirectory, "bthprops.cpl");
if (File.Exists(path))
{
   Process.Start(path);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it does not work for me. Any insights?

Comment: can you start bthprops.cpl?
"If you can't find it, click Start, click Run, type bthprops.cpl, and then click OK. If this doesn't work, your Bluetooth software might come from someone other than Microsoft, for example, from your computer manufacturer. See the documentation that came with your computer for more information."
http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/bluetooth/en-us/default.mspx

Comment: @AccurateEstimate: Read my answer to understand why it does not work for you.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer does NOT work on a 64 bit Windows if your application is compiled as 32 bit. I analyzed this to the bottom:

```
Control.exe bthprops.cpl
```

will call

```
RunDll32.exe Shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL bthprops.cpl
```

which will execute the function `Control_RunDLLW()` in Shell32.dll

This function is programmed extremely sloppy because it has absolutely no error handling.

It seems that there is a bug in the 32 bit version of `bthprops.cpl`
On my 64 bit Windows the 32 bit `RunDll32.exe` with the 32 bit version of `bthprops.cpl` does NOT work, while others like the 32 bit versions of `Desk.cpl` or `Appwiz.cpl` DO work correctly.

The following code will work no matter if you compile as 32 bit or 64 bit.

```
[DllImport("Kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection(ref IntPtr ptr);

[DllImport("Kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool Wow64RevertWow64FsRedirection(IntPtr ptr);


// Example: s_CplFile = "bthprops.cpl"
public static void StartCPL(String s_CplFile)
{
    String s_Path = Environment.SystemDirectory + "\\RunDll32.exe";
    String s_Args = "Shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL " + s_CplFile;

    IntPtr p_Wow64 = IntPtr.Zero;
    bool b_Revert = Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection(ref p_Wow64);
    try
    {
        Process.Start(s_Path, s_Args);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (b_Revert)
            Wow64RevertWow64FsRedirection(p_Wow64);
    }
}
```